# Forge - selecting elements across multiple models is slow

Tags: autodesk-forge

What is the best way to select elements across multiple models when using aggregatedView?

Answer (score 0):

Use viewer.getAggregateSelection(); is the best way.

Take a look at this blog post for more details:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher

Are you still experiencing slowness ?

Comment: Yes, can the material of the selection be customised? Do you find that having a custom material is better than using setThemingColor?